# EF Core migration - byte[] to base64 in SQLite without sqlean-crypto

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I'm trying to create a migration in EF Core 6.0 which changes a column from the type `byte[]` to a `base64` encoded string (yes I know, but for ... reasons). This migration must preserve the existing data.

Just changing the CLR datatype and adding a migration results unsurprisingly in a migration which just drops the old column and adds a new one and looses the data.

An easy solution would of course be create a new temporary column, migrate the data to that column using `migrationBuilder.Sql(...)`, then drop the old column and rename the temp one.

The trouble I have with that though is doing the base64 conversion entirely in SQL. Easy enough with a real database but SQLite doesn't have a base64 encoding function without loading the `sqlean-crypto` extension.

Trying `update table set tempCol=encode(oldCol, 'base64')` just throws an error "unknown function encode". It works from the SQLite terminal but you must first download sqlean-crypto and do `.load ./crypto`

My questions

1. Is there anyway of making a sqlite extension available to EF Core so the above approach can be used?
2. If not, is there anyway of accessing the database programmatically using `SqlCommand` etc within an EF Core migration? All the reading I've done so far on that seems to suggest not and you basically limited to code-first edits or raw SQL to do your migrations.

If not I guess I'm stuck doing the "migration" outside of a migration as part of the seeding process and I'd have to keep the old column around forever.